# Replacing part of folder name in multiple subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to write a batch script to replace the filler XXXX in a given folder structure for future projects. The batch should be put in the folder and be run there.

e.g.:

- New_Project_0XXXX

  - 01_0XXXX_Misc

    - 01_0XXXX_Archive

      - SomeOtherName
    - 02_0XXXX_NewData

      - MoreOtherStuff
  - 02_0XXXX_OtherStuff

and so on.

The filler is to be replaced with a user prompted project number. I've had this first shot at it, but the problem is, that it renames the first layer and then it can't find the others.

```
set /P oldString="To Replace:"
set /P newString="Replace with:"
call :rendirs %oldString% %newString%

:rendirs
for /f %%a in ('dir /s /ad /b "*%~1*"') do (call :rename %%a %~1 %~2)

:rename
set oldname=%~n1
call set newname=%%oldname:%~2=%~3%%
ren %oldname% %newname%
```

I've got the idea of cutting the for loop to 'dir /ad /b' so it doesn't involve the subfolders yet and recursively calling the :rendirs function for the subfolders, but it doesn't work.

```
:rendirs
for /f %%a in ('dir /ad /b' "*%~1*"') do (
 call :rename %%a %~1 %~2
 for /f %%i in ('dir /ad /b') do (
  cd %%i 
  call :rendirs %~1 %~2
 )
)
```

How do I make cd work inside the loop or how do I ensure the script can find the subdirectories?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `move` command, instead of `ren`, because it can rename full qualified pathnames.

Then the `:rename` block looks like

```
:rename
set oldname=%1
call set newname=%%oldname:%~2=%~3%%

move %old_fullname% %newname%
```

BUT, you still have the problem of the renaming order.
First the top level directory is renamed, then all others will fail.

To solve this, you could reverse the dir list

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with that. However, your comment on reverting the dir list got me thinking. I'm now printing the dir list into a temporary .txt file and reverting that file with sort.exe and got it working like this.

Comment: @SLTArnsberg - Write your solution as an answer, and accept your own answer.(unless someone comes along in the mean time and provides an answer you like better). BTW -  I think jeb used the wrong word "revert" - English is not his native language.. Better would be either "invert", or "reverse".

Comment: @dbenham True, true, I changed the word, btw. "Arnsberg" is the name of a city nearby

Answer (score 1):

I would accomplish your task using the following script (see the explanatory remarks in the code):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0." & rem // (target root directory)
set "_MASK=%~1"    & rem // (directory name pattern)
set "_SEARCH=%~2"  & rem // (search string)
set "_REPLAC=%~3"  & rem // (replacement string)

rem // Skip all actions if no search string is provided:
if defined _SEARCH (
    rem /* Traverse directory hierarchy in reverse manner,
    rem    so lowest level directories come first: */
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%D in ('
        dir /S /B /A:D-H-S "%_ROOT%\%_MASK%" ^| sort /R
    ') do (
        rem // Store path and name of iterated directory:
        set "DIRP=%%D" & set "NAME=%%~nxD"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoide loss of `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Actually rename iterated directory here:
        ren "!DIRP!" "!NAME:%_SEARCH%=%_REPLAC%!"
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Given it is named `renaming.bat`, it should be used with the following arguments, based on your sample data and assuming `XXXX` is to be replaced by `1234`:

```
renaming.bat "*_0XXXX*" "_0XXXX" "_01234"
```